# Why isn't gaming on SEDE?

Tags: support, status-completed, data-explorer, data-dump

I noted that Gaming data is included in the [monthly Data Dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/creative-commons-data-dump-nov-10/), but isn't (yet?) loaded to [SEDE](http://odata.stackexchange.com/).

Will it be loaded this time (and I'm just being impatient) or is there some issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gaming data is now available:

https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/queries

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like SEDE has the most recent data dump for any of the sites yet.  Presumably when it is updated, all sites present in the data dump will be loaded.  I don't see any reason why they'd include a site in the data dump but not on SEDE.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer because the Data Explorer hasn't been updated yet. It's still ending on September 30th.